# Problem with non-normal residuals (lmer function)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, biostatistics

I work with animal personality and I am trying to analyze individual differences in response to certain stimuli.

Taking this particular dataset as an example, I am analyzing how much distance animals covered when place inside a maze (a measure of exploration). This histogram shows how my data is dispersed, with a lot of animals covering very little distance and some which are more exploratory (I made the breaks very small so you can get a better idea of the values).

[image]

I tried analyzing this with linear mixed models with the lmer function, I had some models, but taking one for example:

```
z2 = lmer(Dist ~ Group + (1|Animal), data=expl, REML=F)
```

Where Dist is the Distance I am interested in.

Group is a factor of two levels of animals that had different experimental treatments.

And Animal is the individual identity of the animals, used as a random factor.

Using plot(z2) this is what I get, showing that the residuals clearly do not follow a normal distribution.
[image]

I tried transforming my data to normality with the square-root to see if the model would fit better and this was the distribution:
[image]

And the residuals:
[image]

Using the square-root transform generated a better fit, but I have two problems:

1. Even then, the residuals barely followed a normal distribution for this particular model and did not fit normality for some of the other models tested.
2. I am afraid using the square-root transform will make the interpretation of my model a lot more difficult and if possible I would like to not transform my data before analyzing.

---

My question is, how to best approach analyzing this data which is very skewed towards the lower tail of the curve?

And could I use the lmer function as is and proceed with my model selection, even if the residuals do not fit normality?

---

@ErikRuzek here is the `qqnorm()` for this particular model I showed in the original post

[image]

This second one is for a different model which according to a Shapiro-Wilk test did not have normal residuals

[image]

Comment: If your concerned about normality assumption on the error term, why not take a nonparametric or bootstrap approach. Regarding the square root transformation what convinces you that the residuals are not close to normal? Regarding your second question difficulty of interpretation is not a good reason to abandon a model.

Comment: Can you show us the qqplot of the standardized residuals? I think this also comes out of the `plot()` function for a `lmer()` model.

Comment: @MichaelR.Chernick sorry, I should have been more explicit about that, I rand a Shapiro-Wilk test on the residuals. For this particular model I showed, the p-value was 0.06, but for other models, it was below 0.05. I would love to take a nonparametric approach, but I don't know how with this type of modelling analysis, I'm a beginner in statistics and R and am not sure which function would be best to analyze this kind of data. Do you mean a `glmm()` approach?

Comment: @ErikRuzek, unfortunately, it does not come out with the plotted model, but I will post it to the answers using the `qqnorm()` function. :)

Answer (score 5):

Try fitting a gamma generalized linear model via the `glmer()` function from the `lme4` package:

`m <- glmer(Dist ~ Group + (1|Animal), family = Gamma(), data = expl)`

Since `Dist` seems to be exclusively positive ($Y \gt 0$) and you generally have a higher frequency of smaller distance values (resulting in a right-skewed distribution), a gamma GLMM may be more appropriate. Then follow up with model validations, e.g.:

```
plot(resid(m, type = "pearson") ~ fitted(m))
qqnorm(resid(m, type = "pearson"))
qqline(resid(m, type = "pearson"))
```

Also if possible try to avoid transformations of the dependent variable. Instead find another distribution that better matches the nature of your dependent variable.

I should also add that if you have any other questions regarding mixed modelling in R, consult this site first: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html